# Routing Controllers in Subfolers

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using a folder structure for my controllers in Codeigniter. They are as follows

- Folder1
- ---Controller1
- ---Controller2
- Folder2
- ---Controller3
- ---Controller 4

In the config file I have the following code

```
$route['folder'] = 'folder1';

$route['folder1/controller1'] = 'folder1/controller1';
$route['folder1/controller1/(:any)'] = 'folder1/controller1/$1';

$route['folder1/controller2'] = 'folder1/controller2';
$route['folder1/controller2/(:any)'] = 'folder1/controller2/$1';



$route['folder'] = 'folder2';

$route['folder2/controller3'] = 'folder2/controller3';
$route['folder2/controller3/(:any)'] = 'folder2/controller3/$1';

$route['folder2/controller4'] = 'folder1/controller4';
$route['folder2/controller4/(:any)'] = 'folder1/controller4/$1';

$route['default_controller'] = 'folder1/controller1';
```

But when I navigate on my browser http://localhost/projectname/ It doesn't load the default controller as set in the config file. which is folder1/controller1.
Can anyone please help?

Much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: default controller is enforced to be in top level of controllers folder. so it will not route to inside another folder. theres different ways around this - you can do a redirect to another controller. or in application/core/ folder -> MY_Router https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/CI3-default_controller_route_with_sub_folder

Comment: First need to know your version of codeIgniter

Comment: Is there a way to remove this forced functionality without breaking the entire framework? Also I'm using version 3.0.6

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['folder'] = 'folder1';
$route['folder'] = 'folder2';
```

Please remove one of these lines. Also add default_controller top of routes.php file.

Comment: Done that, but still not working. From the comments above, it is discussed that the default controller has been forced to be at the top level. Just need to know if there's a way around this without breaking the framework